# File upload progress in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-boot, file-upload

To upload a file in spring boot one can use something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    storageService.store(file);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
        "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

and it works fine.

My problem is how can I extend this code to get some kind of updates during upload. For example: one enent every 10% of completed upload.
Is there any kind of mechanism which creates such events during upload? Can I overwrite some internal spring method to make it work?

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible.For example, It is like a copy from one location and pastes in another location. paste might take more time since it is a write operation and during that time if the source changes mean current paste process will not aware of it.

You have to re-upload that file.

Comment: Sure, but during copy-paste you can see progress bar of copying. I'm looking for something similar in this case. Just done from backend side, not front-end as in all tutorials I have found.

Comment: I think you have to develop your own logic here

Answer (score 2):

To get progress update callbacks add the following bean to your application:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver createMultipartResolver() {

  final CommonsMultipartResolver cmr = new CommonsMultipartResolver();

  cmr.setMaxUploadSize(10000000); // customize as appropriate
  cmr.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");  // important to match in your client
  cmr.getFileUpload().setProgressListener(
      (long pBytesRead, long pContentLength, int pItems) -> {
        // insert progress update logic here
      });

  return cmr;
}
```

Also add the following property to your application properties:

```
spring.http.multipart.enabled = false
```

Note: It's important that your client application matches the expected content encoding (`UTF-8` in this example). If not then a temporary `FileUpload` object will be used instead of the one that we customize in the above code. This is probably a bug in `CommonsFileUploadSupport.java` because it copies over all other members of the original `FileUpload` into the temporary, omitting the listener.